# Rstudioの起動

Tags: r

Windows8環境でRstudioを使っています。仕事の都合上多数のpackageをインストールする必要があったため行ったところ、Rstudioの起動時間が遅くなり時々フリーズします。Rstudioが起動するときにすべてのpackageを読み込むためではないかと思います。（R単独の起動時間は変わっていません）
Rstudio起動時にpackageの読み込みを最小限にして、library()コマンドで必要に応じて読み込む方法などありましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

RStudio は設定により前回の作業環境を .RData から読み込むようになっているので，起動が遅くなっているのはそのせいではないかと．

Tools -> Global Options の [General] にある [Restore .RData into workspace at startup] のチェックを外すと次回起動時から作業環境の復帰を行わなくなるので起動は速くなると思います．